# can logged LDAP user login to internal web portal?

Tags: php, wordpress, active-directory, ldap

I am a creating Internal Web Portal using WordPress and windows active directory based user can able login to internal web portal.

Now client asking if this is possible if user logged in local machine via active directory, is it possible to allow user automatically login to Web portal re-entering user name and password?

Is it possible? any help and guide much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean log in WITHOUT re-entering username and pw, or, they do re-enter it, but it's the same as their computer login???

Comment: thats correct same as their computer login.